# Can't load AKAudioFile into AKSampler

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I'm trying to use `AKSampler` on a simple iOS project to load a file and play it when tapping the device's screen. 
I did the same steps with `AKSamplePlayer` and it worked fine, But I rather use the `AKSampler`, and also I get a strong feeling of missing something.
I've tried the `play()` method, and also the one with the midi note. 
Which one is right? Do they both work?Besides, `AudioKit` looks so promising.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    var sampler = AKSampler()
    var tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {


    super.viewDidLoad()
        do
        {
            let file = try AKAudioFile(readFileName: "AH_G2.wav")
            try sampler.loadAudioFile(file)
        }
        catch
        {
            print("No Such File...")
        }

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewTapped))


        AudioKit.output = sampler
        AudioKit.start()
    }

    @objc private func viewTapped()
    {
        sampler.play(noteNumber: 60, velocity: 80, channel: 0)

        print("tapped...")
    }
}
```

Edit: 
My problem is actually with the `loadAudioFile` method, the `AKAudioFile` itself is good, and the `AKSampler` plays a default sine sound.
I tried also the `AKAudioFile` methods for creating player and sampler didn't.

```
let file = try AKAudioFile (readFileName: "AH_G2.wav")
player = file.player
sampler = file.sampler
```

I also tried to add the wav file using the menu, no change.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation, there is just the one play() method, but it has default values for noteNumber, velocity, and channel:

```
@objc open func play(noteNumber: MIDINoteNumber = 60,
                         velocity: MIDIVelocity = 127,
                         channel: MIDIChannel = 0) {
        samplerUnit.startNote(noteNumber, withVelocity: velocity, onChannel: channel)
    }
```

Changing the MIDI note will change the pitch/speed of the sample playback (60 is standard, 72 is double speed, 48 would be half speed etc), and changing the velocity will change the volume.

NB: the title of your post is 'AKSampler doesn't play', but I ran your code (changing the sample, of course) and it played just fine on my iPad.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, @c_booth. You did help me to understand the play() method. But I still can't make it work on my iPhone nor the simulator.  As I said, same code work perfect with the **AKSamplePlayer**, so I don't think the problem is in the audio file. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I've had Xcode respond inconsistently to files dragged into the Navigator, so you might want to try adding the file via Add File in the file menu.  Maybe also try restarting in a new project, in case something has been accidentally changed.  But I just checked again, and your code is working fine for me in an iPhone 8 simulator.

Comment: Could you please tell me the exact steps you used for adding the audio file to the project?

Comment: File > Add Files to "projectName" or alt-cmd-A.  Drag-and-drop worked too, but I have had troubles with this in the past.  Other than the filename, I've literally just pasted in your code to my ViewController file.

Comment: Got it! I did everything from the top, but you've said "Other than the filename", so I used a different file, and guess what? It worked. Turned out that the file I have used was a mono one, I guess `AKSampler` doesn't support that while `AKSamplePlayer` does. Thank you so much @c_booth.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried a different audio file and it worked fine.
The first file was a mono file, so my conclusion here is that the `AKSampler` does not support mono files. Would love to hear more on that.

Comment: Well, It wasn't a mono/stereo issue. I did some more experiments and the only thing I can say for sure is that there is an issue with wav file generated by pro-tools. When I switched to reaper everything went smooth.